# Express hacer una petición contra el mismo endpoint

Tags: nodejs, express

Tengo una ruta en **express** a la cual le puedo enviar un `array`. Cuando me llega ese `array` tengo que hacer tantas peticiones como el número de elementos del `array` contra la misma ruta. Para ello cambio los datos del `body` en función de lo que tenga el `array`.

El problema es que obtengo el error:

> can't set headers after they are sent.

Un ejemplo sería el siguiente:

```
const postExample=async (req, res, next)=> {
  const {
    some
  }
  =req.body;

  if (some)) {
    return Promise.all(_.map(some, s=> {
          req.body.some=null;
          req.body.data= s.data;
          return postExample(req, res);
        }

      )) .catch(e=> next(e))
  }
  //.....
  //... operaciones
  //.....
  return res.json({data: 'test'})
}
```

Algui

Gracias.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que probablemente esta respondiendo un timeout antes que termine tu petición, como esa ya es una respuesta que fue enviada cuando hacer el res json resulta que los headers no se pueden modificar. Puedes extender el tiempo de respuesta de tu API. aunque pude ser que se esta demorando demasiado